# How to quote all meta-characters in a regex string

Tags: erlang

I need to replace substrings by other strings, and there is no replace in string:, but in re:

However, in order to use re:replace, I need to quote all regex specific meta-characters like [ . etc

In ocaml, it is called Str.quote.

```
 val quote : string -> string

 Str.quote s returns a regexp string that matches exactly s and nothing else.
```

from http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html

What is this function called in Erlang?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of quoting regexp special characters you should consider converting your string to a binary and using [`binary:replace/3,4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#replace-3).

Answer (score 2):

Found it in Elixir, called regex:escape. Converted to Erlang it looks like this (need to look into unicode and return binary flags).

```
escape(String) ->
    re:replace(String, "[.^$*+?()[{\\\|\s#]", "\\\\&",[global]).
```

See [`Regex.escape/1` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#escape/1).

```
{:ok, pattern} = :re.compile(~S"[.^$*+?()[{\\\|\s#]", [:unicode])
@escape_pattern pattern

def escape(string) when is_binary(string) do
    :re.replace(string, @escape_pattern, "\\\\&", [:global, {:return, :binary}])
end
```